# unable to load html with swf in webview in android

Tags: android, android-webview, flash

I am trying to use **webview** in **android** to load a **local html** which has an **swf embedded**. 
But when executing the app I am getting the following message

**"To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash version 11.1.0 or greater is installed"**

And on trying to download the flash player , i get the message that **Adobe flash player is not supported by your device**.

My device is *samsung galxy s2*.

If flash player is no longer supported, how can such cases be handled. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to download and install flash player from [www.aptoide.com](http://www.aptoide.com/). Needed to install their apk first.